# Creating Arrays of Parents and Children

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, and I know the desired output, but I can't quite get my head around how to achieve it

The initial indexes are the "parent" id's, and the arrays contained within are the children, but some children are also parents

My array:
```

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 5
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 2
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 3
    1 => 4
  ]
  5 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 6
  ]
  6 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 7
    1 => 8
  ]
  9 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 10
    1 => 22
  ]
  10 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 11
  ]
  11 => array:10 [▼
    0 => 12
    1 => 13
    2 => 14
    3 => 15
    4 => 16
    5 => 17
    6 => 18
    7 => 19
    8 => 20
    9 => 21
  ]
  22 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 23
  ]
  23 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 24
    1 => 25
  ]
]
```

```

The Resulting array:
```

```
0
9
0,1
0,5
0,1,2
0,1,2,3
0,1,2,4
0,5,6
0,5,6,7
0,5,6,8
9,10
9,22
9,10,11
9,10,11,12
9,10,11,13
9,10,11,14
9,10,11,15
9,10,11,16
9,10,11,17
9,10,11,18
9,10,11,19
9,10,11,20
9,10,11,21
9,22,23
9,22,23,24
9,22,23,25
```

```

I'm thinking to use recursion, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the result

Edit: Further information:

If I take:

```
  22 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 23
  ]
  23 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 24
    1 => 25
  ]
```

23 is the parent of 24 and 25, , 22 is the parent of 23, therefore 22 is the grandparent of 24 and 25:

```
9,22,23,24
9,22,23,25
```

That's how you get the list (9 is obviously the parent of 22, therefore the grandparent of 23 and great grandparent of 24 and 25)

Comment: Maybe I'm just being dense, but the specific relationship between your input and output doesn't seem obvious to me?

Comment: Need more explanation, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've added more information at the bottom, I should also add that the list may be any number of children

Comment: Can you provide the code that you already tried ? More information about where you are stuck ? You would learnmore and better if we take it from where you begin to have trouble than just throw a solution at you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit advanced stuff but you can use [`Iterators`](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) to achieve this.

First, we have to extend [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) to serve our need:

```
class FlatRecursiveIteratorIterator extends RecursiveIteratorIterator
{
    private $directory;

    public function __construct(
        Traversable $iterator,
        $mode = RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY,
        $flags = 0,
        array $directory
    ) {
        // Set array for children lookup.
        $this->directory = $directory;
        parent::__construct($iterator, $mode, $flags);
    }

    public function callHasChildren()
    {
        if ($this->getDepth() === 0 && is_array($this->current())) {
            return true;
        }

        // See if children array availale in the top most array
        // (lookup by id).
        return !empty($this->directory[$this->current()]) &&
            is_array($this->directory[$this->current()]);
    }

    public function callGetChildren()
    {
        return new RecursiveArrayIterator(
            $this->getDepth() === 0 
                ? $this->current()
                : $this->directory[$this->current()]
        );
    }
}
```

Having this class we use it in combination with [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) and [`RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator.php) to create needed `$iterator`:

```
$skip = [];
$iterator = new FlatRecursiveIteratorIterator(
    // This filter helps up skip top level array elements
    // if they have ancestors. Pay attencion that $skip passed by reference.
    new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($array),
        function ($current, $key, $_) use (&$skip) {
            return !(is_array($current) && isset($skip[$key]));
        }
    ),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    0,
    $array
);
```

Then we can traverse this `$iterator` with a pretty simple non-nested loop:

```
$stack = [];
foreach ($iterator as $node) {
    $depth = $iterator->getDepth();    
    if ($depth > 0) {
        $skip[$node] = true;
    }

    // Use ternary operator as top most array has ids as keys,
    // but inner arrays have ids as values.
    $stack[$depth] = $depth === 0
        ? $iterator->key()
        : $node;

    // We have to slice out stack, as it may contain elements
    // from previous iterations.
    echo implode(',', array_slice($stack, 0, $depth + 1)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/36c13f50de455f18f7bfe3837410a7b8e430938e).

This might look like a lot of code, but actually, it is not. And we need to take into account that most of the work is done by [**Standard PHP Library**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php). We only have written the most case specific code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, please see my edit for my solution